# Can I update a Google Sheets spreadsheet using a Google Form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to store data about foster animals from a google form. Essentially, it will just input the information entered into the spreadsheet. This works well for the first submission, but is not useful for if I would like to change information recorded for a specific animal. I think name is my best bet for a unique identifier, so I figure that I would want to write a script that would search for the name through a given column if the same name was entered and then repopulate that row.

Is this even something I can do to begin with? In addition, am I thinking about it in a very backwards way? If more information is needed, I am happy to provide it.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit

Answer (score 0):

#### The best approach in this situation is to make use of Apps Script triggers.

You could start by using an `onFormSubmit` which will run when a user ends up submitting the form needed.

This is an **installable trigger** which means that it will require a setup first.

If you plan on using the form for modifying the information, you can easily create an `id` field for instance in the form and setup a script something similar to this:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SS_ID').getSheetByName('SHEET_NAME');
    let idCol = ss.getRange('ID_RANGE').getValues();
    let submissions = e.namedValues();
    for (let i = 0; i < idCol.length; i++) {
        if (idCol[i][0] == submissions.Id)
        //update the sheet accordingly
        else {
        //add the new values to the sheet 
        }
    }

}
```

In order to gather the submissions from the form, the `e.namedValues` has been used. Assuming, you have a column in your spreadsheet in which you store the id of each animal which corresponds to an item in your form, you can simply check if the submitted form is addressed for an existing item - so you can update it with the new info or simply just add the new submissions to the sheet.

Please bear in mind that you will have to adapt this so it fits your current setup.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
- [Apps Script Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).